# What am I missing? Font color in CSS

Tags: html, css

If I write the same block of code below but don't include the "body" element (which also doesn't appear to do anything) then my h1 text stays black. Why is this happening? If I understand correctly, I should be able to add the h1 portion and it should change colors right?

edit: I want to clarify that I'd like to exclude the "body" portion, and want to understand why I can't. As another example, I previously had size settings for the image in the code. When I placed these settings before the h1 portion, h1 changed colors. If h1 was after, then it stayed black again.

```html
   <style>
    
    body{
      color: pink;
    }
    h2{
      color: blue;
    }
    
    </style>

    <h1 id="title" class="title">Katherine Johnson</h1>
    <div id="img-div">
      <img id= "image"    src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/26646856911_ca242812ee_o_1.jpg" alt="Katherine Johnson" class="center">
      <h2 id="tribute-info"><ul> <li>Born in White Sulphur Springs, West Virginia, in 1918, her intense curiosity and brilliance with numbers vaulted her ahead several grades in school.</li> </li>By 13, she was attending the high school on the campus of historically black West Virginia State College. </li> <li>At 18, she enrolled in the college itself, where she made quick work of the school’s math curriculum and found a mentor in math professor W. W. Schieffelin Claytor, the third African American to earn a PhD in mathematics. </li> <li>She graduated with highest honors in 1937 and took a job teaching at a black public school in Virginia. </li> </ul></h2>  
      <a id="tribute-link" target="_blank" href="https://www.nasa.gov/content/katherine-johnson-biography"> Learn more about Katherine here</a>
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided class and id to make CSS effective.
Use class/id to make CSS effective instead of an anchor tags.

```
<style>

body{
  color: pink;
}
h2Class{
  color: blue;
}

</style>



<h1 id="title" class="h2Class">Katherine Johnson</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because the body itself is a element.
Headings, paragraphs etc. do not inherit color from their parent instead they use the initial color assigned to them by default which is black
but if you want to assign a different color to all of them you can use the Universal Selector `*` like this:

```
* {
  color: pink;
}
```

The Universal selector will add the color or any property you write here to all the html elements.